# Export data in R for use in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: r, format

I need to create a table of the following data which can be used in LibreOffice Writer. So, I created a dataframe but now I do not know how to export the data in a way that I can use it in LibreOffice Writer.
Do I need to export it as a Calculator file and then copy it in Writer using write.table?
Does anybody of you know other possibilities?
Is it possible to format the data in R so that there is a frame around the table, for instance?

```
Male <- 920; Male
Female <- 414; Female
Total <- Male + Female; Total
b <- data.frame(Male, Female, Mixed, Unknown, Total, row.names = ""); b
```

Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 0):

One method for "exporting" formatted output is the use of the `capture.output`-function. This doesn't really have a lot of options for formatting, certainly not putting frames around text. It does let you use the formatting of the print methods that display results at the console. Try this:

```
capture.output(b, file="test.txt")
```

Now if you look at the `test.txt` file in your working directory you should see (after removing the two names in the dataframe call that you had not defined):

```
  Male Female Total    
  920    414  1334
```

There are more flexible methods of formatting output, with the `rmarkdown` and `knitr` packages being very popular. I think that LibreOffice can handle html tables which would allow you to apply frames. You can use the demo() function on one of the examples in thae knitr package:

```
install.packages("knitr", dependencies=TRUE)
install.packages("shiny", dependencies=TRUE)
library(knitr)
demo('notebook', pac='knitr')
```